# How to get repository name in a Github Organisation Folder in Jenkins ?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, github-organizations

I have a Github Organisation Folder project on Jenkins with a number of repositories, is there a way to get the name of the current repository from where we did the build Job?

Answer (score 2):

Are you aware that this plugin is deprecated, at this point in time (for about a year now)?
If need be, read [this blog post](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/01/17/scm-api-2/)

In both cases, you should be able to access the repo url via:

```
// scm instanceof GitSCM
gitUrl = scm.getUserRemoteConfigs()[0]?.getUrl()


// Altenatively
girUrl = env.'GIT_URL'
```

So you could parse this url to access the repo name per-se, for instance.

Comment: "The functionality of this plugin has been migrated to the GitHub Branch Source plugin." The GitHub Organization folders still exist, they just moved to a different plugin. So the question is a valid one.

Comment: True, and in both cases you can get the scm url from the environment and the scm object itself